# Blink once in List

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to add an item in a list and make a blink
The example code is below.

I have problems with my application which should do the following:

When I press the add button, it blink for 5 sec.
When I press the other buttons, it blink also for 5sec.

Now the problems:

If I press the Add button several times in a row, it runs incorrectly.
Example, If I press the Add button twice in a row:
The first in the list is executed (lstmuestra[0].blink=true), then the second (lstmuestra[1].blink=true).
After 5 seconds the first one changes (lstmuestra[0].blink=false) as the state changes the whole list is repainted because second link is still there (lstmuestra[1].blink=true) and shows again.

Please I need it to appear in the correct order and only once
Thank you.

**My code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-fast-3fu2d?fontsize=14)**

César

Comment: Share the code in your question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that handles every click by a given id instead of create a function for each action:

Instead of this:

```
 const cmdBlink0 = () => {
    ModifyOrederData(0, { blink: true });
  };
  const cmdBlink1 = () => {
    ModifyOrederData(1, { blink: true });
  };
  const cmdBlink2 = () => {
    ModifyOrederData(2, { blink: true });
  };
```

you can have just one function like this:

```
 const cmdBlinkN = ( id ) => {
    ModifyOrederData( id, { blink: true })
  }
```

and change the onCLick event on every item:

```
      <button onClick={() => cmdBlinkN(0)}>Blink ord 0 </button>
      <button onClick={() => cmdBlinkN(1)}>Blink ord 1 </button>
      <button onClick={() => cmdBlinkN(2)}>Blink ord 2 </button>
```

This worked on the codesandbox but im not sure if this will be useful to you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bartik-8njjs

Comment: Hello Ricardo Gonzalez, thank you for your time and comment, but it is not what I am looking for.

What I want is that I only blinked once, either with a new item or by calling a specific item

Comment: Sorry ive misread your problem, but think i fixed that. The issue that you has is that you were not resetting the blink to false, so every time that you set it true the other ones stayed blink=true ive modified the codesandbox so you can check see if it works for you  https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bartik-8njjs

Comment: Other thing that ive just saw is that you are handling your animation through css, i think that it would work as you want if you put the time as infinite and handle the animation as youve done it in with the state of the component

Comment: Ricardo Gonzalez,
I just changed the code with useReducer and it got better.
It's 90% of what I want.
Look at the code again. Thank you

Comment: Great decision! use Reducer will get easier to handle this kind of changes